# pick out only files that were uploaded from the $_FILES array

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

I've noticed when uploading multiple files using php, that the array contains data for all input fields from the form.

Suppose I have a from with 3 input fields, and a user were to upload only 2 files, how can I pick out only those two files from the array, maybe using some array function or anything else, so I can only loop thru those files.

I was trying using `array_filer` on `tmp_name` but cannot figure how to proceed.

```
if($_FILES && isset($_POST['handle'])) {

    $numFiles = count(array_filter($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));

    if( $numFiles <= 2 ) {
        // files that were uploaded will not have a blank value
        $filesUploaded = array_filter($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

            print_r($filesUploaded);// for testing
            // loop through the above array
            foreach($filesUploaded as $key) {// stuck
                //echo each files attributes
                echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key].'<br>';
                echo $_FILES['file']['name'][$key].'<br>';
                echo $_FILES['file']['type'][$key].'<br>';
                echo $_FILES['file']['size'][$key].'<br>';
                echo $_FILES['file']['error'][$key].'<br>';
                // proceed with the rest of the processing
            }
    } else {
        echo 'Too may files uploaded';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error A';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are expecting like this?

To check whether the file uploaded or not:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {}
```

Edited:

```
$fileUploads=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$countUpload=0;
foreach($fileUploads as $fileUpload){
 if($countUpload>2) {
     echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     //move_upload_file
 }
 $countUpload=$countUpload+1;
}
```

Comment: Not quite. From the array that's created when a user submits a file upload form, i'm trying to pick only the files that are uploaded and not blank ones, and loop through only them. In php, suppose a form had 10 file input fields, and user chose only 5 files, php creates a blank value for each of those files a user did not use. Trying to exclude those and loop thru the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Check error status:

```
if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0) {
    echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];
}
```